# How to check if any turtle ahead "in a same patch" not in a patch ahead

Tags: netlogo

I referred many example to check whether a turtle is moving in front of another turtle but I have a different scenario.

In my work, when my turtles move (with their respective forward values, like fd 0.1 + random 0.9) I found there are more than one turtle in a single patch. Now, I want to

1. check who is moving ahead or who is behind the other.
2. ask the turtle who is moving in front among them, to check further the presence of another turtle in front of it and if not then to keep moving.
3. ask the turtle who is behind to slow-down.

I followed the code example of car movement (and other examples as well) where there is the case of one turtle in a patch, so the use of "patch-ahead" primitive works fine but in my case before checking turtle on patch-ahead I want to first check within a patch.

To make more clear I am attaching a small part of the snapshot of my work.

[image]

The direction of movement of these turtle is set fixed, turtles with similar headings are moving in their specified paths. Turtles with different headings does not come in the path of other moving turtles. The code I tried is as below

```
 to control-speed
   let other-people-here min-one-of other people-here [ distance myself]  
   ;with the above code each turtle find the other turtle but not the turtle ahead 
    so tried the x-position value for heading 270 and 90 and 
    y-position value for heading 0 and 180

   ifelse other-people-here = nobody  [speed-up-people] 
    [  
     if heading = 270 
    [ ifelse precision [xcor] of self 3 < precision [xcor] of other-people-here 3 
     [let people-ahead-x other-people-here slow-down-people people-ahead-x ]
     [let people-ahead-x self slow-down-people people-ahead-x] 
    ]

     ; if heading = 90 [do same]
     ; if heading = 0 [do same and check for ycor]
     ; if heading = 180 [do same and check for ycor]
   ]
   if move-fd < move-fd-min [set move-fd move-fd-min]
   if move-fd > move-fd-limit [set move-fd move-fd-limit ]
 end

 to speed-up-people
    set move-fd (move-fd + (speed-up))   ;show move-fd
 end

 to slow-down-people [people-ahead-x]
    set move-fd [move-fd] of people-ahead-x  ;show move-fd
    set move-fd move-fd - slow-down          ;show move-fd
 end
```

This does not work. I could not understand why the value of "move-fd" once reached 0 does not increase again, ultimately turtles stop moving in case of slow-down procedure call.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you could take a look at the **Traffic 2 Lanes** example model *from NetLogo 6*. It doesn't rely on patches for its collision checking, so it might be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will see and try. Hope I could able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the code which I did finally to sort out my problem as directed by sir @Nicolas Payette.

```
to control-speed
   if (pxcor > -69 and pxcor < 10) and (pycor > -21 and pycor < 142) [
   let people-per-patch count people-here
   if people-per-patch = 1 [speed-up-people]
   if people-per-patch > 1 [
   let people-ahead-x other people in-cone (1 + move-fd) 180 
   let person-ahead-x min-one-of people-ahead-x [distance myself]
   if person-ahead-x != nobody [
      set move-fd [move-fd] of person-ahead-x
      slow-down-people
     ]
   ]
 ]
  if move-fd < 0 [set move-fd slow-down]
  if move-fd > move-fd-limit [set move-fd move-fd-limit ]
end

to speed-up-people
  set move-fd (move-fd + (speed-up))
end

to slow-down-people
  set move-fd move-fd - slow-down
end
```